# How to pick value from a particular column in R

Tags: r

My data is in the following form:

```
y<-data.frame(atp=c(1,0,1,0,0,1),
              ssmin=c(2,NA,3,NA,NA,1),
              Day_1=round(runif(6,5,11),0),
              Day_2=round(runif(6,88,110),0),
              Day_3=round(runif(6,90,211),0))
```

I need to create a new column which picks the value from `column 3, 4 or 5` depending on the value in `column 2`(ssmin).
The output would be like this:

```
FDRT<-c(89,NA,175,NA,NA,7)
```

I am trying out the following command but this does not help

```
y$new<- y[which(y$atp==1),na.omit(2+y$ssmin)]
```

Can any one help me how to write a code for it as my data is in large chunks and i cannot write value individually.

Comment: If you are going to use random data in a question like this, use `set.seed` so we can get the same results.

Comment: Did you mean to say "depending on the value in column 1" or 3?

Comment: I meant depending on the value in column SS min i.e if its 2 then it picks value of Day_ 2, if 1 then it puts value of Day_1 column.

Answer (score 2):

I think this might be what you're trying to do, but I'm not certain:

```
set.seed(1)
y<-data.frame(atp=c(1,0,1,0,0,1),
              ssmin=c(2,NA,3,NA,NA,1),
              Day_1=round(runif(6,5,11),0),
              Day_2=round(runif(6,88,110),0),
              Day_3=round(runif(6,90,211),0))
y
#   atp ssmin Day_1 Day_2 Day_3
# 1   1     2     7   109   173
# 2   0    NA     7   103   136
# 3   1     3     8   102   183
# 4   0    NA    10    89   150
# 5   0    NA     6    93   177
# 6   1     1    10    92   210

x <- vapply(y$ssmin, function(x) unique(grep(x, names(y), value = TRUE)), 
            vector("character", 1L))

Z <- vector(length = length(x))
for (i in sequence(nrow(y))) {
  Z[i] <- if (is.na(x[i])) NA else y[i, x[i]]
}
Z
# [1] 109  NA 183  NA  NA  10
```

Comment: Can anyone help me how to do the same operation with the help of data.table as it is taking a lot of time for data.frame?
Is it useful to shift from data.frame to data.table?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, the last line you give almost solves your question. You just have to modify it slightly to get only the diagonal elements of the right hand side and only assign it to the applicable elements of the vector `new`. Here's the modified code.

```
y[which(y$atp==1), "new"] <- diag(as.matrix(y[which(y$atp==1),na.omit(2+y$ssmin)]))
```

Answer (score 1):

not very elegant but short

> y

```
  atp ssmin Day_1 Day_2 Day_3
1   1     2     5    97   123
2   0    NA     8   108   165
3   1     3    10   109   190
4   0    NA     9   110   177
5   0    NA    10    91   182
6   1     1     7    94   141

> apply(y,1, function(r)r[r[2]+2])
[1]  97  NA 190  NA  NA   7
```

for a more robust maintainable solution you probably want to hardcode the column names using ddply or somesuch.

Comment: But what to do if you dont know column number and only its name?.. As i am working on a very large data set.

Comment: I used the following statement for my actual data set
frame$FDRT_TSH<-apply(frame,1,function(r)r[r["ssmin"]+15])
It showed me the following error
Error in r["ssmin"] + 15 : non-numeric argument to binary operator

i checked the class of ssmin which is numeric. Then can you help why this error is coming